# General formula for $x^{\pm n}$, when $x,n \in \Bbb R$

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers, products

I have tried to find a general formula outlining the algorithm of operation that is $x^n$, however, it was much harder than I thought. I ended up with a pretty big monster of an equation that  takes into account positive, negative and non-integer exponents. Here it is:
$$x,n \in \Bbb R, \quad0^0=1$$ $\equiv$

$$x^{\pm n} = ((\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor n \rfloor} k^0 \times x + 0^{\pm1\times\lfloor n \rfloor})\times (\sqrt[\frac{1}{\{n\}+0^{\pm1\times\{n\}}}] \frac{x^{1+\lceil\{n\}\rceil}}{x})\times 0^{(\pm1 \times n)\mp (\pm1 \times n)}) + ((1\div(\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor n \rfloor} k^0 \times x + 0^{\pm1\times\lfloor n \rfloor})) \times (1 \div (\sqrt[\frac{1}{\{n\}+0^{\pm1 \times\{n\}}}] \frac{x^{1+\lceil\{n\}\rceil}}{x}  ))\times 0^{n\pm n})$$

**Two questions:**

Is this formula correct? I have checked it with a calculator, but checking through a program like Mathematica would be safer.

Does there exist another and/or better general formula for a real number raised to the power of a real number (I have yet to integrate imaginary and complex numbers into this formula)? If not, has this one been found before?

PS, some of the parentheses are just there for clarity. If anyone finds these mathematically superfluous parentheses distracting, I'll remove them.

Comment: In which sense is $x^n$ itself not already the formula you want? Your proposal seems to use much worse things than that internally ...

Comment: @Troposphere It is, but it doesn't show the algorithm. I'm no expert in computation, but wouldn't one need to do something along the lines of what I've done above (but in code) in order to compute the operation that is $x^n$? There's probably pre-programmed stuff that will take an exponential expression and give one the answer, but in the absence of that, one would have to code the algorithm oneself. So, my question was, how would one do that? This is what I came up with. There's probably an optimized version of my formula, or a different, better one, but this is the one I was able to make.

Comment: Computers don't _evaluate formulas_ -- they _execute programs_. Your formula looks like it arises out of a determination to express something without _openly_ using conditionals or loops, but instead multiplying by strategic factors that _just happen to be zero_ for parts of the formula you need to ignore in any given case. That's a desire that sometimes grips math hobbyists (who seem to be concerned that a recipe that divides anything into cases is "less matematical" than one that laboriously avoids that), but such a goal is completely alien to _actually making a computer do something_.

Comment: @Troposphere I think I understand what you mean; if one were writing a computer program, one would rather split it up for the different instances; one for negative exponents, one for positive, one for negative fractional exponents, etc. However, I thought it was efficient to combine everything into one program. Is it more efficient to split it up into if statements, like "if $n=\frac ab$, then ans $= (\root b \of x)^a$, and then three other if statements? Is it generally or always the case that multiple if statements is better than a program that laboriously combines everything?

Comment: Efficiency is a hairy subject. Software professionals will generally tell you to _write what is clearest_ for this sort of thing and let the compiler sort it out, _unless_ you know the particular code you're writing is performance critical. And in the latter case, the correct course of action is to _measure what is fastest_ rather than be satisfied with any rule of thumb that may be outdated. (There was a time a decade or two ago where a conditional jump could take as much time as a dozen or more straight-line calculation steps; but it is not generally that bad on modern hardware anymore).

Comment: When each of the things you're choosing between is _expensive_ -- which they will generally be if you're computing floating-point powers and don't have dedicated hardware to do it for you -- it will (almost?) never be most efficient to just compute all of them and then destroy all but one of the results at the end. And it is _definitely_ not the clearest way to say things either.

Comment: @Troposphere I don't know all of the terms you used, but I think I got the gist (and I'm planning on learning computation anyways, so I'll be learning the terms some time in the future). Thanks for the information, I was definitely under the impression that a recipe dividing things into multiple cases was less "mathematical", as you said, but I now see this impression can be impractical, unnecessary and is ultimately based on an arbitrary view of what math is supposed to be. However, it was quite fun and educational for me to laboriously combine every real case into that one equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier way.
$$a^{b} =\begin{cases}
\text{undefined} & a=b=0\\
0 & a=0,b\neq 0\\
1 & a\neq 0,b=0\\
\exp( b\log a) & a\neq 0,b\neq 0
\end{cases}$$
This works for more general $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ as well. To compute $\exp$ one can use
$$\exp z=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
And to compute $\log$ one can use
$$\log z=\log |z|+i\operatorname{arg}z$$
Where $\arg$ is the principal argument. Letting $x,y\in\mathbb R$ the definition is
$$\arg( x+iy) =\begin{cases}
\arctan( y/x) & x >0\\
\arctan( y/x) +\pi  & x< 0,y\geq 0\\
\arctan( y/x) -\pi  & x< 0,y< 0\\
\pi /2 & x=0,y >0\\
-\pi /2 & x=0,y< 0\\
\text{undefined} & x=y=0
\end{cases}$$
And for $x\in\mathbb R_+$ one can use the integral definition of the logarithm:
$$\log x=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\mathrm dt$$
This is the standard definition of exponentiation and I think avoids a lot of the confusion present in your approach.

Comment: $$0^0=1~ \text {or undefined }$$